# Printer proxy between different subnets

Tags: proxy, subnet, forwarding, printer

I have a Xerox WC 7120 network printer on IP a.a.a.a/24. An eternal client application prints to that printer via a VPN tunnel. I will have to move that printer to a different subnet c.c.c.c/24.

Is there a way to create a virtual RAW printer to use as a proxy to forward the print jobs sent to a.a.a.a to c.c.c.c so that this change is transparent to the client application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just forward TCP 9100 from another IP.  You could NAT at the network edge, or use something like `iptables` on Linux, or `netsh portproxy` on windows if you put a device at `a.a.a.a`.

```
# linux
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d a.a.a.a --dport 9100 -j DNAT --to c.c.c.c:9100

# windows
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=9100 connectaddress=c.c.c.c connectport=9100 protocol=tcp
```